# Is Method Overloading and Method Overriding both dynamic Polymorphism?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I am learning JAVA from `Core Java An Integrated Approach` by Dr.R.Nageswara Rao.

The book mentions that Method Overloading and Method overriding both are types of Dynamic Polymorphism. But after referring to the online blogs and websites I have found that Method Overloading is Static and Method Overriding is Dynamic polymorphism. I am not sure which one to follow.

`Explanation from the book:`

**Method Overloading**

```
public class Sample {
    void add(int a, int b){
        System.out.println("Sum of Two: "+ (a+b));
    }
    void add(int a, int b, int c){
        System.out.println("Sum of Two: "+ (a+b+c));
    }
}
```

The above class has two methods. The question is who will decide which method to call? Is it Java compiler or JVM? Because the methods are called by using an object, the compiler can not decide at the time of compilation which method is actually called by the user. It has to wait till the object is created for the Sample class. And the creation of an object takes place at runtime by JVM. Now, JVM should decide which methods actually called by the user at runtime. Hence its dynamic polymorphism.

**Method Overriding**

Here also JVM decides which method is called depending on the data type(class) of the object used to call the method. Hence method overriding is also a type of Dynamic Polymorphism.

`Note:`  Method overloading and method overriding using static methods, private methods, and final methods are examples of static polymorphism.

Comment: That explanation from the book is incorrect. The compiler picks what signature (which exact overload) will be called, the runtime/JVM picks which implementation of that signature will be executed (which is why the actual object is needed.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method overriding is dynamic, because  the decision on which method to call occurs at runtime. method overloading is static, because the decision is made at compile type, based on the number and types of the parameters.

Overriding:

```java
    public class A {
       public void foo(){System.out.println("I am A");}
    }

    public class B extends A {
       public void foo(){System.out.println("I am B");} 
    }

    A z = getAnObject();
    z.foo();
```

Let's say that `getAnObject()` returns an Object of type `A`, but the compiler has no way to tell if  its runtime class is `A` or `B`  or something else. Indeed, in different invocations, the returned object may be of different types. If it happens that its type is `B`, the above will print "I am B".

```java
    public class A {
       public void foo(int x){System.out.println("with int param");}
       public void foo(String x){System.out.println("with String param");}
    }
 
    A a = new A();
    a.foo(42);
```

That prints "with int param". The compiler knows that the param is an `int`, not a `String`, so it knows at compile-time which `foo()` to use.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, even with single argument, the method to be called is determined during compile time. In below code, always "Object called" is printed regardless of whether the object is null or Integer

```java
public class MethodOverloadingRandomObjectTest {
    public static  void doSomething(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("Object called");
    }

    public static  void doSomething(char[] obj) {
        System.out.println("Array called");
    }

    public static  void doSomething(Integer obj) {
        System.out.println("Integer called");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // compilation error for below
        // doSomething(null);
        
        // try object with random runtime value of null to avoid compilation error
        Object random = Math.random()*10>5?999:null;
        System.out.println("object value by random:"+random);
        System.out.println("object class: "+(random==null?"null":random.getClass()));
        // "Object called" printed for both Integer value and null value
        // execute multiple times
        // surprise surprise, for Integer object, "Object" method is called
        // this is because method overloading is compile time polymorphism
        doSomething(random);
    }
}
```